# CSS sprites not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have 10 pixel-size image in the spirit image i want to apply that image as a background to this header text my css code:

```
.header-text {
    background:url(images/sp-images.jpg);
    background-position-x: -0px;
    background-position-y: -28px;
}
```

[image]

my html code:

```
<h1 class="header-text">let's Knockout Poverty in India!</h1>!
```

[i want to apply that red shadow image as a background to the header text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvqd2.jpg)

Comment: Its not clear, please clarify.

Comment: Also “knockout” isn’t a verb — you want “Let’s Knock Poverty Out in India!”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS sprites cannot tile in both directions. If you stack the sprites vertically, you can tile them horizontally; if you line them up horizontally, you can tile them vertically.

Looking at your image, it appears to have four images in a two-by-two grid. Set up that way, you will only be able to use those sprites in a non-repeating background.

Comment: If all his background images are no-repeats, there's no problem with his setup

Comment: Sure. I'm just guessing based on the fact it's a tiny image and he's referring to it as "that red shadow image". I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , [background-position-x and -y are supported only in IE, Chrome and Safari,  but not in Firefox or Opera](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y)

What you should be writing is;

```
.header-text {
background:url(images/sp-images.jpg) 0 -28px;
```

}

I don't know if you want it to repeat or not. The default behavior is repeat. If you want it to repeat, then you'll have to mov the rest of the images out of the way...

Comment: `background-position-x` and `-y` are also supported in Chrome 1 and above, and Safari 2 and above.